# Group By and displaying entries under date

Tags: php, sql, mysql, group-by

Here's my data:

```
id date  
1 2009-01-01 10:15:23  
2 2009-01-01 13:21:29  
3 2009-01-02 01:03:13  
4 2009-01-03 12:20:19  
5 2009-01-03 13:01:06
```

What I'd like to do is group by each date and then list the id numbers below each date.  Should I be getting the distinct date values and then cycling through them to get the entries that fall on the date?  is this efficient?

so my output would look like:

```
2009-01-01  
1  
2   
2009-01-02  
3  
2009-01-03  
4  
5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT DATE(date) as mydate, id FROM your_data_table ORDER BY mydate, id";
$result = $pdo->query($query);

$oldDate = false;
while ( list($date, $id) = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ) {
    if ( $oldDate != $date ) {
        echo "$date\n$id\n";
        $oldDate = $date;
    } else {
        echo "$id\n";
    }
}
```

Instead of doing it in several queries, you just fetch all the data at once. If you only need some dates then you just put a `WHERE` clause before the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Your stored dates have time information (the type of the column is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP), in order to do a group by, you need to extract only the date part your timespan, you can use the [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

Comment: Right, and that's fine.  

Lets just say I pull the distinct dates.  Am I doing that as one separate query?  Then cycling through the results and running another query to get all entries that match the date?  Just doesn't seem too efficient...

Comment: no, you're just doing one query and discarding the 'time' portion of that column.