# Grouping dates in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My question is almost exactly the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623968/group-by-and-displaying-entries-under-date), except that I'm using Python and Django instead of PHP.

The task is to take:

```
id date  
1 2009-01-01 10:15:23  
2 2009-01-01 13:21:29  
3 2009-01-02 01:03:13  
4 2009-01-03 12:20:19  
5 2009-01-03 13:01:06
```

And output:

```
2009-01-01  
1  
2   
2009-01-02  
3  
2009-01-03  
4  
5
```

I can manually hack something together by looping through the sorted dates and outputting HTML into a string in my python view file, but I'm wondering: is there's a better way using a Django template or a nifty Python feature?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can solve this with the *regroup* and *date* templatetags.

```
{% regroup object_list by start_date|date:"Y-m-d" as objects_by_day %}
{% for d in objects_by_day %}
### DO SOMETHING HERE
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was most of the way there but didn't realize you could mix in the date filter.  Many thanks for this!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: good god, how didn't I know about this

Comment: it's faster to use start_date.date if you need 'the date portion'

Comment: consider my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597940/246241 if performance is an issue

Comment: This answer is amazing!

Answer (score 16):

[`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is your dear, dear friend:

```
import itertools

dates = [
   (1,'2009-01-01 10:15:23'),
   (2,'2009-01-01 13:21:29'),
   (3,'2009-01-02 01:03:13'),
   (4,'2009-01-03 12:20:19'),
   (5,'2009-01-03 13:01:06'),
]

for key,group in itertools.groupby(dates, key=lambda x: x[1][:11]):
   print key
   for element in group:
      print '   ', element
```

The above code prints the following:

```
2009-01-01 
    (1, '2009-01-01 10:15:23')
    (2, '2009-01-01 13:21:29')
2009-01-02 
    (3, '2009-01-02 01:03:13')
2009-01-03 
    (4, '2009-01-03 12:20:19')
    (5, '2009-01-03 13:01:06')
```

Comment: Excellent! itertools.groupby is just what I was looking for.

Comment: If you are going to do it in the view, you want something like this:

"def sidebar_date_list():
from itertools import groupby
data = [datetime.date(post.created_at.year, post.created_at.month, 1) for post in Post.objects.filter(publish=1).order_by('-created_at') ]
return {'months': [k for k,_ in groupby(data)]}

Notice that the SQL has to be sorted for groupby() to use." Lifted from here:
http://www.djangrrl.com/view/using-python-str-datetime-lists-and-sets-to-group-dates/

Comment: Or like this if you want to group by days: "def sidebar_date_list():
 from itertools import groupby
 data = [datetime.date(post.created_at.year, post.created_at.month, post.created_at.day) for post in Post.objects.filter(publish=1).order_by('-created_at') ]
 return {'days': [k for k,_ in groupby(data)]}"

Comment: Wade's method below, for doing this in the template worked better of me.  Added bonus was that I could use the date-based generic views and get rid of some code.

Answer (score 9):

When doing reports on larger datasets `itertools.group_by` might be too slow. In those cases  I make postgres handle the grouping:

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day','timestamp')
qs = qs.extra({'date':truncate_date})
return qs.values('date').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('date')
```

Answer (score 8):

These are all reasonable answers if the OP could use python in the template code. (And on that account, I would favor the itertools.groupby() solution.) But you can't use python in template code. In the best case, you'd write a templatetag that performed this operation. And there is already a templatetag that does this.

To do the grouping in Django inside the template, use *regroup*:

```
{% regroup people by gender as gender_list %}

<ul>
{% for gender in gender_list %}
    <li>{{ gender.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in gender.list %}
        <li>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Example lifted from [Django regroup documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/). regroup is available in django [0.96](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/), [1.0](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/), and [1.1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), at least.

If you gave me an idea of what is passed through to the template, I could hack up an example that uses your data.

Also, there is a [blog post](http://www.djangrrl.com/view/using-python-str-datetime-lists-and-sets-to-group-dates/) in which DjangoGrrl works through exactly this question.

Comment: Templating languages tend to provide enough of the same language constructs that you can convert between the two easily (they share the same target bytecode).

Comment: Not to be rude, but do you program in Django? For practical purposes, there are only rudimentary comparisons and assignment operations. Check out what is available without using templatetags:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using 0.96 but this is a great resource for those on 1.0 or greater!

Comment: It turns out that regroup is available in 0.96. http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/
I didn't claim that originally because I had not programmed in 0.96 and had no inkling that you were using it. Give it a try if you still want to do the transformation in the template.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier if you used your database's date formatting functions to strip off the times (in the select). You can then group by the formatted column (using a column alias).

After that, you can use a loop with a little logic to transpose the results to what you want. I haven't used django's template system yet, but here's what the logic would look like in Python:

```
>>> rows = [(1,'2009-01-01'), (2,'2009-01-01'), (3, '2009-02-02'), \
(4, '2009-02-02'), (5, '2009-02-02')]
>>> topdate = None
>>> for r in rows:
...     if topdate <> r[1]:
...             topdate = r[1]
...             print r[1]
...     print r[0]
... 
2009-01-01
1
2
2009-02-02
3
4
5
```

There should be a straight-forward way to convert this to django template code.

Comment: I can group the data, but what would the "little logic" inside the templating system look like?

Comment: I'm not convinced you can do this in Django templates. Even if you could, you wouldn't want to. It's better to do it in:
(1) the view code or (2) a templatetag where you can use real python.

Comment: I consider templates to be part of the view in the MVC model. I think that whether you decide to do any data formatting in your views (rather than the controller) depends on the situation, but it's necessary sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would really prefer to do this in a view function using Python. Django's templating system isn't designed to handle this type of stuff.

Comment: If you want to use a view function (not in the template, as originally described: "is there's a better way using a Django template or a nifty Python feature?"), then Dana the Sane's code is on the right track, though I think that the itertools.groupby() solution is more complete and pythonic.