# Django model group by datetime's date

Tags: python, django, django-models

Assume I have a such model:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to regroup them as **list of lists** which each list of lists contains Entities from the same date (same day, time should be ignored).

How can this be achieved in a pythonic way ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a small function to extract just the date:

```
def extract_date(entity):
    'extracts the starting date from an entity'
    return entity.start_time.date()
```

Then you can use it with [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

entities = Entity.objects.order_by('start_time')
for start_date, group in groupby(entities, key=extract_date):
    do_something_with(start_date, list(group))
```

Or, if you really want a list of lists:

```
entities = Entity.objects.order_by('start_time')
list_of_lists = [list(g) for t, g in groupby(entities, key=extract_date)]
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that will group by date *and* time, when OP wants to group by date only. You might be interested in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236865/grouping-dates-in-django

Comment: @Jordan Reiter: the question was edited. I've edited the answer and now it works as OP wants.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the answer:

```
Product.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( date_created )'}).values('day') \
               .annotate(available=Count('date_created'))
```

But there is another point that:
the arguments of date() cannot use the double underline combine foreign_key field,
you have to use the table_name.field_name

```
result = Product.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( product.date_created )'}).values('day') \
           .annotate(available=Count('date_created'))
```

and product is the table_name

Also, you can use "print result.query" to see the SQL in CMD.