# Django - get distinct dates from timestamp

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to filter users by date, but can't until I can find the first and last date of users in the db. While I can have my script filter out dups later on, I want to do it from the outset using Django's `distinct` since it significantly reduces. I tried

```
User.objects.values('install_time').distinct().order_by()
```

but since `install_time` is a `timestamp`, it includes the date AND time (which I don't really care about). As a result, the only ones it filters out are dates where we could retrieve multiple users' install dates *but not times*.

Any idea how to do this? I'm running this using Django 1.3.1, Postgres 9.0.5, and the latest version of psycopg2.

**EDIT:** I forgot to add the data type of `install_time`:

```
install_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's some sample output from the Postgres shell, along with a quick explanation of what I want:

```
 2011-09-19 00:00:00
 2011-09-11 00:00:00
 2011-09-11 00:00:00 <--filtered out by distinct() (same date and time)
 2011-10-13 06:38:37.576
 2011-10-13 00:00:00 <--NOT filtered out by distinct() (same date but different time)
```

I am aware of `Manager.raw`, but would rather user `django.db.connection.cursor` to write the query directly since `Manager.raw` returns a `RawQuerySet` which, IMO, is worse than just writing the SQL query manually and iterating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388559/django-model-group-by-datetimes-date

Comment: @thatwasbrilliant That was exactly what I was looking for; thanks! Kind of odd that it only took 30 min on SO when it took 2 hrs on Google w/ no result.

Comment: You need to work on your Google skills :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When doing reports on larger datasets `itertools.group_by` might be too slow. In those cases  I make postgres handle the grouping:

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day','timestamp')
qs = qs.extra({'date':truncate_date})
return qs.values('date').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('date')
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet @till-backhaus; I needed this for another project.

Comment: This is the version that I try to keep up to date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746532/246241

Answer (score 0):

I've voted to close this since it's a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388559/django-model-group-by-datetimes-date), so here's the answer if you don't want to visit the link, courtesy of [nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17160/nosklo).

---

Create a small function to extract just the date:
   def extract_date(entity):
       'extracts the starting date from an entity'
        return entity.start_time.date()

Then you can use it with [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

entities = Entity.objects.order_by('start_time')
for start_date, group in groupby(entities, key=extract_date):
    do_something_with(start_date, list(group))
```

Comment: It's still useful to have your question around since you couldn't find the answer with 30 mins searching google. You should accept this answer and let it be :) Next time somebody uses your language to search this problem, this Q will come up on google.

Comment: @YujiTomita That's why I'm closing, not deleting. I still have closed answers show up on Google.