# Grouping by months in Django and retrieving as datetime.date()

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-aggregation

I was looking around to see how to group a django queryset by months. I've finally found this very helpful piece of code:

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day','timestamp')
qs = qs.extra({'date':truncate_date})
return qs.values('date').annotate(Sum('amount')).order_by('date')
```

from [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-sales-by-month)

It worked fine, however the `date` returned is a string and not a proper `datetime.date` and I can't use `{{date|date:format}}` in the template. It seems the the original sender (Oli) had the same problem. Although the guy who is answering says it works with postgres I didn't have any success with SQLite.

Is it possible to convert from the string to datetime in the query or template. Or do I have to loop over all entries?

Sorry for posting in a separated trend, but I don't have enough privilegies to just comment in the original one.

Answer (score 7):

You can try use the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) template tag to group by months at the template level.  Make sure you context-data is sorted:

```
{% regroup queryset by date_field|date:"M, Y" as objects_by_month %}
{% for group in objects_by_month %}
    {{ group.grouper }}
    {% for object in group.list %}
        {{ object }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But then the "amount"  will not sum all the entries for a month as I need (the other post was about it).
my current query looks like this:


`truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'data_insercao')`
    

`fichas_report = Ficha.objects.extra(select={'month': truncate_date}).values('name', 'month').                     annotate(number_entries=Count('pk')).order_by('-month')` 

It gives me a list of names and entries by month.