# Annotate (group) dates by month/year in Django

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate-functions, django-orm

Using the Django `DateQuerySet` I'm pulling related years for `item` objects from a `Group` query.

```
>>> Group.objects.all().dates('item__date', 'year')
[datetime.date(1990, 1, 1), datetime.date(1991, 1, 1), ...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

Now I want to perform a count by distinct year on these dates. I thought this would work:

```
>>> Group.objects.all().dates('item__date', 'year').annotate(Count('year'))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'year' into field.
```

But looks like I'm missing something. How can I fix this query?

I've also tried this query:

```
>>> (Group
     .objects
     .all()
     .extra(select=
         {'year': 
          connections[Group.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('year', 'app_item.date')}))
ProgrammingError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "app_item" LINE 1: SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('year', app_item.date)) AS...
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Item.objects.all().\
        extra(select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM date)"}).\
        values('year').\
        annotate(count_items=Count('date'))
```

You might want to use `item_instance._meta.fields` instead of manually specifying "date" in the MySQL statement there...

Also, note that I started with `Item` QuerySet instead of `Group`, for the sake of simplicity. It should be possible to either filter the `Item` QuerySet to get the desired result, or to make the `extra` bit of MySQL more complicated.

**EDIT:**

This might work, but I'd definitely test the guts out of it before relying on it :)

```
Group.objects.all().\
    values('item__date').\
    extra(select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM date)"}).\
    values('year').\
    annotate(count=Count('item__date'))
```

Comment: Well, the `Group` query is what makes this interesting. I'm already doing other stuff related to it, so I can't just start from the `Item`.

Comment: Same error "missing FROM-clause entry for table..."

Comment: Can you post your models? I have this working on a simple case with no such error.

Comment: My models are slightly complicated, but I'm happy to hear it works for you. I'll see if I can get it to work on my side. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work. It groups by date field but not by year.

Comment: Seems like extra() is being deprecated. What is the official way of doing this without extra()?

Comment: @MadWombat Where did you see extra() being deprecated? I can't find it mentioned in the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Comment: @frnhr right on the page that you linked it says "Use this method as a last resort. This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future. Use it only if you cannot express your query using other queryset methods. If you do need to use it, please file a ticket using the QuerySet.extra keyword with your use case"

Answer (score 30):

For anyone finding this after django 1.9 there is now a `TruncDate` (`TruncMonth`, `TruncYear`) that will do this.

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

(Group.objects.all().annotate(date=TruncDate('your_date_attr')
                    .values('date')
                    .annotate(Count('items'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @mycroft from what I can see, this was added in 1.10

Comment: indeed - thanks @IanClark https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#module-django.db.models.functions.datetime

Comment: Should you use this, or Extract? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#extract