# Python Django group by date

Tags: python, django, group-by

I'm building a web app using Django. One of my models is this:

```
class Change(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(User)
   project=models.ForeignKey('Project')
   starttime=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
   endtime=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   worktime=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)#worktime is in hours
   comment=models.CharField(max_length=500)
   flagged=models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

As you can see the `starttime` and `endtime` are `datetime` objects. I want to run a sql query grouping the results by date. But since the objects are `datetime`, they are grouped by date and time. Is it possible? I looked at both Python and Django docs without find anything useful. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [Annotate (group) dates by month/year in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837227/annotate-group-dates-by-month-year-in-django) and [Django group by dates and SUM values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099697/django-group-by-dates-and-sum-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
select date(starttime) as simple_date
from your_table
group by simple_date
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python or Django? While this expresses a solution in raw SQL, it doesn't show how to use that in either Django or Python, so strictly speaking it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

You could use `datetime.datetime.date('starttime')` to get the date from the DateTimeField. Then take a look at the [Django docs on aggregation for grouping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/).