# Django: Query Group By Month

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How to calculate total by month without using extra?

I'm currently using:

- django 1.8
- postgre 9.3.13
- Python 2.7

Example.

[image]

**What I have tried so far.**

```
#Doesn't work for me but I don't mind because I don't want to use extra
truncate_month = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month','day')
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(is_deleted = False,company = company).extra({'month': truncate_month}).values('month').annotate(Sum('total'))

----
#It works but I think that it's too slow if I query a big set of data
for current_month in range(1,13):
    Invoice.objects.filter(date__month = current__month).annotate(total = Sum("total"))
```

and also this one, the answer seems great but I can't import the TruncMonth module.

[Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

---

P.S. I know that this question is already asked multiple times but I don't see any answer.

Thanks!

---

**SOLUTION**:

Thanks to @Vin-G's answer.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so for

Comment: you could see this example for inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746532/2581266

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho I've already tested that but I can't seem to import the TruncMonth module.

Comment: which version of django do you have?

Comment: django 1.8
but tback said that it's for 1.10 and above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)

Comment: @tback As what I've stated above, I am not sure why I can't import the TruncMonth module.

Comment: @aldesabido: django 1.8 = 1.08 . version 1.10 is two releases later and was released on august 1st 2016.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, you have to make a Function that can extract the month for you:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Func

class Month(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(MONTH from %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()
```

After that all you need to do is

1. annotate each row with the month
2. group the results by the annotated month using `values()`
3. annotate each result with the aggregated sum of the totals using `Sum()`

**Important**: if your model class has a default ordering specified in the meta options, then you will have to add an empty `order_by()` clause. This is because of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

> Fields that are mentioned in the `order_by()` part of a queryset (or which are used in the default ordering on a model) are used when selecting the output data, even if they are not otherwise specified in the `values()` call. These extra fields are used to group “like” results together and they can make otherwise identical result rows appear to be separate.

If you are unsure, you could just add the empty `order_by()` clause anyway without any adverse effects.

i.e.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

summary = (Invoice.objects
              .annotate(m=Month('date'))
              .values('m')
              .annotate(total=Sum('total'))
              .order_by())
```

See the full gist here: https://gist.github.com/alvingonzales/ff9333e39d221981e5fc4cd6cdafdd17

If you need further information:

Details on creating your own Func classes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

Details on the values() clause, (pay attention to how it interacts with annotate() with respect to order of the clauses):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values

> the order in which annotate() and values() clauses are applied to a query is significant. If the values() clause precedes the annotate(), the annotation will be computed using the grouping described by the values() clause.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried your answer but the months is not grouping. It just calculating the total per transaction.

Comment: Kindly see the link below for the result.
https://s32.postimg.org/3ripkuelh/Testdata_result.png

Comment: It finally works now. I just added .order_by() after the last annotate and then it works like a magic. :) Thanks.

Comment: Ah, if you had a default ordering specified in the model class, then yeah that happens (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) I'll edit the answer to add that information as that is a very important part of it for everyone's future reference

Comment: You should just use `ExtractMonth` or  `TruncMonth` directly. `from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, TruncMonth`

Comment: How would I use this solution when overriding `get_queryset` in django admin?

Comment: Is there any way to set month name (Dec, Feb, Mar, etc) instead of (month: 1, month: 2, , month: 3etc). following structure: {"month": "Dec", "count": 5}

Comment: Well this certainly is a blast from the past! @msln You would be better off implementing the conversion of month number to month name string in python rather than using SQL functions as date formatting across database servers differ. That said, if you insist on doing this on the database side, then you'd changed the function name and template to one that's available for the database server you are using. e.g. use TO_CHAR(value, format) for postgres or DATE_FORMAT for mysql. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/Date_and_time_functions

Answer (score 13):

```
result = (
    invoices.objects
        .all()
        .values_list('created_at__year', 'created_at__month')
        .annotate(Sum('total'))
        .order_by('created_at__year', 'created_at__month')
)
```

Comment: Code-only answer is not encouraged, the answer value increase when you add some context to explain how this will solve the problem.

Comment: much simpler than accepted answer. can be written even shorter. no need for all()

Comment: The only change I made for my case was to replace `values_list` with `values` to get a dict instead of a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is the performant option in Python and can be utilized with a single db query:

```
from itertools import groupby

invoices = Invoice.objects.only('date', 'total').order_by('date')
month_totals = {
    k: sum(x.total for x in g) 
    for k, g in groupby(invoices, key=lambda i: i.date.month)
}
month_totals
# {1: 100, 3: 100, 4: 500, 7: 500}
```

I am not aware of a pure django ORM solution. The `date__month` filter is very limited and cannot be used in `values`, `order_by`, etc.

Comment: In Python 3.0 you may need to use i.date().month. Worked for me Django 1.10 + python 3.

Comment: Re: a pure Django ORM solution - see my post below on using the native `datetimes` manager, which is often overlooked.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that Django querysets provide a native [`datetimes` manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes), which lets you easily pull all of the days/weeks/months/years out of any queryset for models with a datetime field. So if the `Invoice` model above has a `created` datetime field, and you want totals for each month in your queryset, you can just do:

```
    invoices = Invoice.objects.all()
    months = invoices.datetimes("created", kind="month")
    for month in months:
        month_invs = invoices.filter(created__month=month.month)
        month_total = month_invs.aggregate(total=Sum("otherfield")).get("total")
        print(f"Month: {month}, Total: {month_total}")
```

No external functions or deps needed.

Comment: This is brilliant ! Thank you.

Suggestion : you should filter not just by month, but also by year, because 2020-10 is not the same month as 2021-10 !

Answer (score 2):

I have a reservation models which have fields like booked date, commission amount, total booking amount etc. and based on the year provided I have to aggregate the reservations by months. Here is how I did that:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth

Reservation.objects.filter(
    booked_date__year=year
).values(
    'id',
    'booked_date',
    'commission_amount',
    'total_amount'
).annotate(
    month=ExtractMonth('booked_date')
).values('month').annotate(
    total_commission_amount=Sum('commission_amount'),
    total_revenue_amount=Sum('total_amount'),
    total_booking=Count('id')
).order_by()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my solution is faster than your. You should profile it. Nonetheless I only query the db once instead of 12 times.

```
#utils.py
from django.db.models import Count, Sum


def get_total_per_month_value():
    """
    Return the total of sales per month

    ReturnType: [Dict]
    {'December': 3400, 'February': 224, 'January': 792}
    """
    result= {}
    db_result = Sale.objects.values('price','created')
    for i in db_result:
        month = str(i.get('created').strftime("%B"))
        if month in result.keys():
            result[month] = result[month] + i.get('price')
        else:
            result[month] = i.get('price')
    return result

#models.py
class Sale(models.Model):
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Published'), default="2001-02-24")

#views.py
from .utils import get_total_per_month_value
# ...
result = get_total_per_month_value()
```

test.py

```
  #
    import pytest
    from mixer.backend.django import mixer
    #Don't try to write in the database
    pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_get_total_per_month():
        from .utils import get_total_per_month_value
        selected_date = ['01','02','03','01','01']
        #2016-01-12 == YYYY-MM-DD
        for i in selected_date:
            mixer.blend('myapp.Sale', created="2016-"+i+"-12")
        values = get_total_per_month_value() #return a dict
        months = values.keys()
        assert 'January' in months, 'Should include January'
        assert 'February' in months, 'Should include February'
        assert len(months) == 3, 'Should aggregate the months'
```