# How to retrive data from db group by month and return zero if no value for certain month in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a table transaction table and I tried this but it give transactions which present in database.

```
class transactions(models.Model):    
amount=models.FloatField()
ts = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

revenueByMonth = transactions.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('ts')).values('month').annotate(c=Sum('amount')).values('month', 'c')
```

It will give:

```
    <[
    {'c': 353.13, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
    {'c': 706.26, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
    {'c': 353.13, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
    {'c': 706.26, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
    {'c': 353.13, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
    {'c': 756.26, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
]>
```

I want sum of amount of each month and if a month have no transaction then it should be return zero.So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I wont call this a duplicate but [Django: Query Group By Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851053/django-query-group-by-month) seems to atleast create a base for what you need. That is grouping by month.

Now for `I want sum of amount of each month and if a month have no transaction then it should be return zero` you can look into [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce). Combine this two and you should have your solution.

Comment: Thanx for your answer.I have tried Coalesce but it doesn't give expected answer.If you have solution then please help me

Comment: First show the piece of code you tried including use of Coalesce

Comment: revenueByMonth = transactions.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('ts')).values('month').annotate(c=Coalesce(Sum('amount'),V(0))).values('month', 'c')