# How i can make a query using django orm group by date

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How I can make a group by date using django Orm
I have a query of sales  I need  return a query group by date sale 
by  in django I don't have any idea how i can make a group by in a query

Comment: You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year)