# Count customers per period

Tags: python, django

In my django project, it is possible to show every customer in the application with `CustomerProfile.objects.all()` and find the creation date of a specific customer with

```
In [12]: cust = CustomerProfile.objects.get(pk=100)

In [13]: cust.user.date_joined
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 43, 51, 925548)

In [14]: cust
Out[14]: <CustomerProfile: FistName LastName's customer profile>
```

According to the creation date, I would like to make a listing of how many customers has been created per day, week, month or year. An example of the result could be

```
...
week 28 : [ 09/07/2017 - 15/07/2017 ] - Count : 201 customers
...
```

I probably need a range `start_date` and `end_date` where we will list that kind of information. `start_date` will be the date of the first customer created and the `start_week` created would be the week of this first_date. Obviously, the end_date is the date of the last customer created and `last_week` is the week of this `end_date`.

For instance, if I select `Per week` in the drop-down menu and press `Apply` in the form, I want to send information to my model in such I could code what I explained.

So far I know how to count the number of client in a range of two date:

```
CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=["2017-09-03", "2017-09-09"])
```

How could I update dates here in such a way we could get a list between the `start_week` and the `end_week`? (A full answer would be appreciated) A full answer would be appreciate, if possible. I think I could find the first and last date with the `.first()` and `.last()` object :

```
first_date = CustomerProfile.objects.first().user.date_joined
last_date  = CustomerProfile.objects.last().user.date_joined
```

Comment: I think this question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746532/2729584 . Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Please read the question again. @J.Doe Although the question is good, there are not many people who will be able to answer this question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the ORM with this? Trivially solvable in SQL:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('week', created) as "week_created",
    count(customerprofile)
FROM customerprofile
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

The form could take in the truncate parameter and then start/stop ranges for filtering the results.