# How do I render objects in a queryset to different tags in template in Django?

Tags: django

So I'm trying to make a simple scheduler with Django, but then got stuck. I have this following code.

```
...
<td class="myClass" data-date="2020-05-15">
    <div class="myContent">today's schedule comes here</div>
</td>
<td class="myClass" data-date="2020-05-16">
    <div class="myContent">today's schedule comes here</div>
</td>
...
```

I have a separate model where each object has two fields-`date`(datefield) and `schedule`(CharField). Let's assume the user can only put one schedule per day. 
So for example if the data is `[{"date":"2020-05-15", "schedule":"Read books"}, {"date":"2020-05-16", "schedule":"Do laundry"}]`, how do I assign each schedule to each date? 
I think I was able to get the objects using query in views.py below, but got stuck on rendering each data(schedule) to each corresponding date in template.

```
from .models import NewEvent

def SchedulePage(request):
    eachDay = NewEvent.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'schedule.html', {'eachDay':eachDay})
```

I believe I'll have to use JQuery here but have no idea on how to do it. I very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your end result shall be this markup:

```
...
<td class="myClass" data-date="2020-05-15">
    <div class="myContent">today's schedule comes here</div>
</td>
<td class="myClass" data-date="2020-05-16">
    <div class="myContent">today's schedule comes here</div>
</td>
...
```

and your model `NewEvent` has the fields `date` and `schedule` then in your template you use a [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to generate the markup:

```
{% for event in object_list %}
    <td class="myClass" data-date="{{ event.date }}">
        <div class="myContent">{{ event.schedule }}</div>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

And one easy way to write the view would be:

```
public class NewEventListView(ListView):
    model = NewEvent
```

The rest is convention with [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). You can override how the list is called in the template, by convention it's `object_list`.

If `date` is really a `DateField` or `DateTimeField`, you can format it to your needs in the template using the [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{{ event.date|date:"YYYY-mm-dd" }}
```

---

This was not part of the question but would pop up eventually when sorting events into a calendar: what if there is more than 1 event per day?

In this case, if `date` is a `DateTimeField` or `DateField`, override [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) of the ListView to [annotate the date (and maybe also the time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year?noredirect=1&lq=1) and then use the [regroup filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) on it to get separate sublists per day.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to put that for loop into <script> tag? I forgot to mention one thing, which is I'm using a pre-designed template, so I cannot directly change the code. So I think I'll have to control them using JavaScript. Would it be possible?

Comment: Certainly, just write JS code instead of HTML - remember to quote any strings explicitly because the template engine will simply output python strings as unqoted strings which in JS are variables and not strings.

Comment: Oh so you mean I can just copy+paste the template tag ```{% for %}...{%endfor%}``` into the ```<script>``` tag?

Comment: yes, just try it. the template language of django is not limited to html. I use it to generate text emails and latex documents, as well. You just have to make sure that what the renderer outputs fits the target syntax.