# Group by month based on DateTime Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model for hotel reservations:

```
class PaymentRequest(SoftDeleteModel):
     class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "PaymentRequests"

    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, default=None)
    customer_first_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    customer_last_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    arrival_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I'd like to do is make a queryset to group my reservations by month and get a count of it.
i.e `{'jan' : 10, 'feb' : 11, etc..}`
I've seen some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year) but does not work quite right, maybe since it was answered 10 years ago.

Comment: Please tell what have you tried and why those answers didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried something on my already existing model and got a result but instead of 'jan', 'feb' I was able to get the month digit, see if this works for you or not

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract

PaymentRequest.objects.annotate(month=Extract('arrival_date','month')).
                       values('month').annotate(dcount=Count('*')).
                       values('month','dcount')
```

Result would be something like this

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 2, 'dcount': 2}, {'month': 12, 'dcount': 1}]>
```